# Is there any contradiction about Declaring global variables in python?

Tags: python, variables

I can see  same output by 2 diff. types of input  regarding the declaration of python's global varible.

phase-1:   https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_variables_global2
(The variable has been declared at the top here )

```
x = "awesome"
z=" code-vi"

def myfunc():
  x = "fantastic"
  z=" c-lan."
  print("Python is " + x+z)

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x+z)
```

phase-2:https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_variables_global4
( here,it is mentioned in the middle that it's  a GLOBAL var unlike phase-1)

```
x = "awesome"
          
def myfunc():
  global x               #  !!!
  x = "fantastic"

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

****what's the specialitry of these 2 types? which is appropriate .?

Comment: If you run the two examples, do you see the difference between them? Can you clarify what it is that still needs answering after you've looked at the two samples' output and let the difference between them inform your understanding of what `global` does?

Comment: If you don't declare it global, the assignment makes it a local variable, not the variable outside the function.